# association issue using model and omniauth identity in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a video model and i'm trying to associate that to omniauth identity. omniauth is working fine. what i'm trying to achieve is when a person is logged in and submits a video i want that video to be able to associate back to the user that submitted it.

I have setup belongs_to :user and a column called user_uid in the video model. I also setup has_many :videos in the user model.

The problem is that whenever I submit a new video I get uid of 1 (which is the default). So what gives?

Video Model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :videos
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

also here is the current schema:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "videos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "submitted_by"
    t.string   "identity_id",  :default => "1"
    t.string   "user_uid",     :default => "1"
  end
```

video submission page code:

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What code do you have to submit the video?  Do you want to store both the Omniauth uid _and_ the User id?  Or just Omniauth uid?

Comment: just the id so later i can reference the id and pull the users's name

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Why can't you simply use the users id instead of the omniauth uid?  That would involve renaming the videos `user_uid` column to `user_id`

Comment: what is the difference between omniauth uid and user id? arent't they the same?

Comment: No, not at all. OmniAuth uid is how the OmniAuth provider refers to this user.  User id is how your Rails app tracks the User internally. Given a OmniAuth provider and uid, a User can be found - but Rails will internally use the simple `id` column to reference the User and associate it with other models.

Comment: i've added the video submit page code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - just don't use the OmniAuth uid for *anything* except logging in.  Once the user logs in, you'll have a User id which Rails can handle much easier.  Rename your `videos`.`user_uid` column to `user_id` and be happy.

Comment: should i create a user_provider column also then?

Comment: ok i named the column but still getting the default value for every submission. do i need to make any changes to the form?

Comment: @SunnyDay - what is your controller code that creates the video model from the form data?

Comment: the name/id is showing properly on my index page (video.user.name or video.user.id) but it always only shows the first user even if user #2 has submitted a video.

Comment: by default for some odd reason it keeps going to user 1. i also removed the :default => 1 in the schema.

Comment: @SunnyDay - please show the controller code.  That is where the model is actually saved to the DB.

Comment: its finally working! i changed the controller code to the following:

ATuser = current_user
ATvideo = @user.videos.new(params[:video])
 thanks for your help!!!